# go mismatched types uint64 and int32

Tags: go

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here with this error, both are of type `syscall.Timeval Usec`

Thanks

```
package common

import (
    "syscall"
)

func getUsecSince(oldTime syscall.Timeval) (result uint64) {
    now := syscall.Timeval{}
    syscall.Gettimeofday(&now)

    for now.Sec > oldTime.Sec {
        result += 1000000
        now.Sec--
    }
    return result + (now.Usec - oldTime.Usec)
}
```

> ./common.go:15: invalid operation: result + (now.Usec - oldTime.Usec) (mismatched types uint64 and int32)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to this is:

```
func getUsecSince(oldTime syscall.Timeval) (result uint64) {
    now := syscall.Timeval{}
    syscall.Gettimeofday(&now)

    // Automatically ignore cases like 12.5 - 11.8
    result = uint64((now.Sec - oldTime.Sec) * 1000000 + int64(now.Usec - oldTime.Usec))
    return result
}
```

By converting to the smallest unit you can ignore the boundary conditions easily as long as there is no overflow during conversion.

Note that if you purposely test the above by using an `oldTime` in the future, the function will fail. You will need to do a check (with both times converted to `Usec`) if you want to cover such cases.

Comment: invalid operation: (now.Sec - oldTime.Sec) * 1000000 + (now.Usec - oldTime.Usec) (mismatched types int64 and int32)

Comment: @dgress added an int64() around the second part. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Use a signed return value (`int64`), like `Timeval.Sec` and `Timeval.Usec`. Use `TimevalToNsec` for portability across operating systems. For example,  `Timeval` fields may be `int32` or `int64`. For a correct result, use,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func getUsecSince(old syscall.Timeval) int64 {
    var now syscall.Timeval
    syscall.Gettimeofday(&now)
    nsecs := syscall.TimevalToNsec(now) - syscall.TimevalToNsec(old)
    return nsecs / int64(time.Microsecond)
}

func main() {
    old := syscall.Timeval{}
    syscall.Gettimeofday(&old)
    time.Sleep(2*time.Second + 42*time.Microsecond)
    fmt.Println(getUsecSince(old))
}
```

Output:

```
2000377
```

Answer (score 0):

`Timeval.Usec` is defined as `int32`. Maybe `result` should be also `int32`? Alternatively if you want to use `uint64` you can cast it by `uint64(now.Usec - oldTime.Usec)`.

Answer (score 0):

result is uint64.
The other operands are int32
Running this

```
now := syscall.Timeval{}
syscall.Gettimeofday(&now)
typeUsec := reflect.TypeOf(now.Usec)
fmt.Printf("type %s, value %d \n", typeUsec, now.Usec)
```

will print

```
type int32, value 238376
```

Strangely, the go documents have the following

```
type Timeval struct {
    Sec  int64
    Usec int64
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the update and the reflect.TypeOf(xxxx) command, that will certainly help in other issues I may come across in following the doc.  I suppose a bug against the go doc is in order.

Comment: Actually I just realized that an easier way to print type is 
fmt.Printf("type  of Timeval.Usec %T \n", now.Usec)